# Given a polynomial $f$, find another, $h$, s.t $wt(h) \leq wt(f)$ and $\dim_K((h)) \leq \dim_{\mathbb{F}}((f))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, finite-fields, coding-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field of characteristic $0$, and $p$ a prime number.

Let $f \in \mathbb{F}[x]/(x^p - 1)$ be given by $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{p-1}a_ix^i$, with $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Let $q$ be a prime number; we need to find a field, $K$, of characteristic $q$, a polynomial $h(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{p-1}b_ix^i \in K[x]/(x^p - 1)$ s.t:

1. $|\{b_i :b_i \neq 0\}| := wt(h) \leq wt(f)$
2. $ \dim_K((h)) \leq \dim_{\mathbb{F}}((f))$, where $(f)$ denotes the ideal generated by $f$ in $\mathbb{F}[x]/(x^p - 1)$.

I thought of using:

> $ \dim_{\mathbb{F}}((f)) = p - \deg(\gcd_{\mathbb{F}}(f, x^p -1))$

and, though it may not be relevant,

> if $L/K$ is a field extension,$f,g \in K[x]$, then $\gcd_K(f,g) =
>  \gcd_L(f,g)$

Here's how I began;
we define $K = \mathbb{Z}/ q\mathbb{Z}$ a finite field of characteristic $q$, and $h = f \pmod q$.

Then showing the first inequality is simple; if $a_i \neq_q 0$, specifically $a_i \neq 0$ and so $wt(h) \leq wt(f)$.

I was thinking that the quoted results can assist with the second, but I haven't managed to see it yet. Any ideas?

Comment: $K$ has characteristic $q$ and $\Bbb{F}$ has characteristic zero, so $\Bbb{F}/K$ cannot be a field extension. No frigging way! $K$ is not even an additive subgroup of $\Bbb{F}$ let alone a subfield. May be I misunderstood something?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen indeed.. overlooked.. Ill need to find another way for the dimension inequality

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you have to use some extension of $\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z}$ in the role of field $K$. I'm fairly sure that I can cook up an example of a high degree factor of $x^p-1$ as $f$ (with coefficients in an appropriate field $\Bbb{F}$) such that $(f)$ has a dimension unequal to that of any ideal of $\Bbb{Z}_q[x]/(x^p-1)$. But, I'm not 100% sure and need to commute next. Have fun :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen check out the answer I posted, if you'd like..

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt:

We take $K = \mathbb{F}_q$. Define $h = f$ mod $q$.

As above, if $h = \sum_{i = 0}^{p-1}b_ix^i$ and $b_i \neq_q 0$, then specifically $a_i \neq 0$ and so $wt(h) \leq wt(f)$.

For the dimension inequality, we use the first stated result;

Also we use:

if $g_1 | f$ in $\mathbb{F}$ then $g_1g_2 = f$, then $g_1g_2 = h$ mod $q$. Meaning $g_1|h$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Suppose that $g = \sum_{i=0}^n c_ix^i = gcd_{\mathbb{F}}(f, x^p - 1)$, then $g$, mod $q$, divides $h$ and $g$, mod $q$, divides $x^p - 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$. Then $deg(g$ mod $q) \leq gcd_{\mathbb{F}_q}(h, x^p - 1)$.

To end, let $(\sum_{i=0}^n c_ix^i)(\sum_{i=0}^m a_jx^j) = x^p -1$ with $n + m = p$. If $c_n =_q 0$ then  $deg(x^p - 1 $ mod $q) < p $ in contradiction.

So we have $gcd_{\mathbb{F}}(f, x^p - 1) \leq gcd_{\mathbb{F}_q}(f, x^p - 1)$ and this proves the claim.

Comment: What do you mean by $f\bmod q$ when $f$ is, say, when $q=11$ and
$$f(x)=\sqrt2+(3+\ln2)x+\pi x^2+(2+i+\root5\of7) x^3?$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen we assume that $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ though

Comment: Ahh! That changes everything. My bad. I guess I was mislead by the fact that you allowed $\Bbb{F}$ to be any field of characteristic zero. But, then I don't understand why you won't just go with $\Bbb{F}=\Bbb{Q}$. It is pointless to have that $\Bbb{F}$ around. When $f$ has integer coefficients the dimension of the ideal it generates in $\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^p-1)$ is automatically equal to the dimension of the corresponding ideal over $\Bbb{F}$. Basically because $\gcd(f(x),x^p-1)$ is the same over $\Bbb{F}$ and $\Bbb{Q}$ whenever $f$ has rational coefficients.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen this problem is only a simplification of a more general result, taken to hold when $f$ doesn't necessarily have coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ but just in $\mathbb{F}$. I wonder, why did you pick that polynomial; and do you think this claim doesn't necessarily hold without the assumption that $f$ has coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ ?